# Prove that $\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{\lambda}\int_0^\lambda\int_0^xf(y)\,dy\,dx = \int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, means, cesaro-summable

Let $f:[0,\infty)$ be Lebesgue-integrable, then prove that

$$\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{\lambda}\int_0^\lambda\int_0^xf(y)\,dy\,dx = \int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$$

This is also known as [Cesàro summability of an integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation).

I know that I should use the Fubini-Toenlli Theorem to change the order of the integration, but I don't know how to get there to do it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a "do my exercise/homework" site. So omit the imperatives, please, and add own thoughts or other efforts.

Comment: I know that I should use the Fubini-Tonelli Theorem to change the order of integration but I don't know how to get there to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f \in L^1$, then $\int_0^x |f(y)| dy = M(y)$ is finite, implying that
$\int_0^x f(y) dy = K(x)$ is also finite $\forall x\in [0,\infty]$. Note that

$$
\sup_{x \in [0,\infty]}(M(x)) = M(x)=\int_0^{\infty} |f(y)| dy<+\infty
$$
Then,
$$
\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_0^\lambda \int_0^x |f(y)| dy dx =
\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_0^\lambda M(x) dx \leq
\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_0^\lambda \sup_x(M(x)) dx = 
\frac{1}{\lambda}M(x)\lambda = M(x)
$$
Since the Lebesgue measure is $\sigma$-finite and
$\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_0^\lambda \int_0^x f(y) dy dx$ is finite,
we can use Fubini's theorem, therefore
$$
\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_0^\lambda \int_0^x f(y) dy dx =
\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_0^\lambda \int_0^{+\infty} f(y) [\mathbb I_{[0,x]}(y) ]dy dx
=
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_0^{+\infty} f(y) \int_0^\lambda \mathbb I_{[0,x]}(y)  dx dy =
\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_0^{+\infty} f(y) \int_0^\lambda \mathbb I_{[y,+\infty]}(x)  dx dy=
$$
$$
=
\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_0^{+\infty} f(y)(\lambda - y)\mathbb I_{[y\leq\lambda]} dy=
\int_0^{+\infty} f(y)(1-y/\lambda)\mathbb I_{[0\leq y\leq\lambda]} \ dy
$$

Note that $|f(y)| \geq |f(y)(1-y/\lambda)|$, because $|(1-y/\lambda)|\leq 1$. Finally, use the Dominated Convergence Theorem, therefore
$$\lim_{\lambda \to +\infty}\int_0^{+\infty} f(y)(1-y/\lambda)\mathbb I_{[0\leq y\leq\lambda]} \ dy=
\int_0^{+\infty}\lim_{\lambda \to +\infty} f(y)(1-y/\lambda)\mathbb I_{[0\leq y\leq\lambda]} \ dy =
\int_0^{+\infty} f(y) \ dy
$$

Comment: Thank you so much! What I needed to understand was where to apply the fubini's. You helped me so much!

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to Cesaro's limit, i.e. if $a_n\rightarrow a$ ($a$ a number) then $\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{k=1}a_k\rightarrow a$. Try to see if you can reproduce the Cesaro arguments for your integral. (Dominated convergence plays a role here)

Let $I=\int^\infty_0 f$ and $J(x)=\int^x_0f$. Given $\varepsilon>0$ let $a>0$ such that $|I-\int^x_0f|<\varepsilon$ for all $x>a$. Then

$$
\frac{1}{\lambda}\int^\lambda_0J(x)\,dx= I +\frac{1}{\lambda}\int^\lambda_0 (J(x)-I)\,dx=I +\frac{1}{\lambda}\int^a_0 (J(x)-I)\,dx + \frac{1}{\lambda}\int^\lambda_a (J(x)-I)\,dx$$

The term $\frac{1}{\lambda}\int^a_0 (J(x)-I)\,dx\xrightarrow{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}0$. The last term is bounded since
$$\Big|\frac{1}{\lambda}\int^\lambda_a (J(x)-I)\,dx\Big|\leq \varepsilon\frac{\lambda-a}{\lambda}$$

Comment: Very nice answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much!